# does sin(a)=cos(b) imply that sin(b)=cos(a)?

Tags: trigonometry

In a correction by our University professor of a midterm exam, I can't understand one inference he did:

[image]

(sorry for bad quality picture, this is a picture taken hastily during class, he moves slides very fast)

But the professor is inferring  that `cos(a)=sin(15t)` implies that `sin(a)=cos(15t)`

Is this true? I tried to plugging values of a and t but the theorem does not satisfy. [image]

I spent hours trying to understand this because I lost grades on this. Maybe I am missing something

If it may help, this is the full picture

[image]

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Think about sign generally. In this problem, I guess you can think about $sin^2+cos^2 = 1$

Comment: Your professor moving slides fast is a poor excuse for leaving the images of text in the question, instead of writing them legibly, let alone with MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

**This is false if you don't have further assumption on $a$ and $b$**.

For example, if $a=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $b=\frac{\pi}{6}$, we have $\sin(a)=\cos(b)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, but $\cos(a)=-\frac{1}{2}$ while $\sin(b)=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Using the Complement Angle Theorem $\cos(\theta)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)$ and $\sin(\theta)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)$,

the equation $\sin(a)=\cos(b)$ is equivalent to $\sin(a)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-b\right)$ while $\sin(b)=\cos(a)$ is equivalent to $\cos(a)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-b\right)$.

But the equality of sines only implies equality of cosines up to a sign. In other words,

$\sin(a)=\cos(b) \implies \sin(b)=\pm \cos(a)$.

---

Seeing the edit of the OP, it seems that all angles are assumed to be in the interval $[0,90^\circ]$, on which all trigonometric functions are positive.

Answer (score 3):

Use $\sin^2 a+\cos^2 a = 1$ to find $\sin a =\sqrt{1-\sin^2(15t)}= \sqrt{\cos^2(15t)}=\pm \cos(15t)$. Since the interval of choice is where both the trigonometric functions are positive, you can conclude that over that interval $\sin a=\cos(15t)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sin a -\cos b = 0 ~\text{ implies angles  a,b are complementary; }~$$

$$ \sin a -\cos b \approx -0.433 ~~ \text {is another relation or equation between a,b} $$

similarly for the other equation.

As given, there is *no implication* of their equivalence when the equations are combined. There is no implication that an identity is involved during all combinations.